# How to run a method after a property has changed angular2-nativescript?

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have a WebView which I initially give a certain URL to visit. That URL at some point is expected to change(a redirect of some sort). When that redirect happens I want to execute a custom method.

How would I establish this logic using angular2-nativescript?

My idea was to have a listener but I couldn't manage to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a property which holds the WebView's `url` property and used `OnChanges` module to continuously check for changes to my property.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `loadFinishedEvent` ?

https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/ui/web-view

Comment: Tried that, no luck ! Also tried        addEventListener("propertyChange",this.check). It fires a couple of times but not in the end.